# Taking extra shopping bags from stores?

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing

Many times I notice people taking extra bags in stores once they are done shopping. If these bags are not used to carry the items they bought but will be used for other reasons (to carry other items) is this considered gezel? Can one assume that the owner won't be makpid because it's cheap & because it may bring in more customers due to the advertising on the bag?

Comment: Why not ask the store owner? If you are buying things already they might not care.

Comment: "Can one assume that the owner won't be makpid because it's cheap" - I suggest that you check this statement. Many localities charge 5 cents per bag, already, and that's becoming the trend, nationally. In such a case, you would definitely be stealing if you made this assumption. even if not, the store owner is paying some amount per bag, and I don't think you can assume that a free bag is a means of your advertising the store to others. Safest way is to ask. And, of course, even if the cashier says, "No", you can still ask a manager or store owner who may override the cashier.

Comment: If it's necessary as a precaution in case one of the bags breaks? That makes sense if they take one extra bag, not if they take a handful of them.